# Selenium how to accept cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Facebook but I'm stuck at the beginning. I'm trying to build a scraper with webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import os 
import wget
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" :2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

#specify the path to chromedriver.exe (download and save on your computer)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Andrea/chromedriver_mac64', chrome_options = 
chrome_options)

#open the webpage
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
```

This part is working, in fact it opens a new tab on Chrome in the Facebook page.

```
#target username
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='pass']")))

#enter username and password
username.clear()
username.send_keys("username")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")

#target the login button and click it
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
"button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

The fields of the form are filled with username and password but the click on the button doesn't work.
The error i receive

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _6lth _4jy6 _4jy1 selected _51sy" name="login" data-testid="royal_login_button" type="submit" id="u_0_5_mO">...</button> is not clickable at point (888, 303). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_9xo4">...</div >(Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.137)
```

The problem seems to be that in the facebook page appears the cookies frame, but i don't know how to automatically accept the cookies.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnJ0f.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can accept the cookies just after the site opens, and before you attempt to access the username/password fields

```
#wait for the pop up and then click accept
cookie_accept_all = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='cookie-policy-manage-dialog-accept-button']")))
cookie_accept_all.click()
```